# Search in MySQL foreign field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm fairly new to PHP and MySQL.

I have two tables as follows:

```
1.`users`: `id`//primary key
         : `name`//user's name

2.`events`: `u_id`//index key and foreign field to users' id
          : `u_name`
```

A user will input an `id` in a form. That `id` will be searched in the `users` table and the relevant details will be taken and inserted in the `events` table.

I've created the foreign fields and and till now I made a function that took `id` as a variable and returned details from the `users` tables as variables which I then inserted in the `events` table. But then, it meant using "a lot" of variables and I thought what was the use of foreign field. 
I'm still learning PHP and don't know how to find and insert using FOREIGN fields from one table to another. I just know how to create foreign fields. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by `don't know how to find and insert using FOREIGN fields from one table to another`

Comment: share the table schema, output from `show create table tablename`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're talking about?
This is how foreign key is created.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE child (id INT, parent_id INT,
                    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Apologize if I didn't understand your question

**UPDATED**

```
INSERT table1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table2
WHERE col1 = 'xyz'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I know how to create the foreign fields. What I don't know is that how to insert values from one table to another and store them?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the user name in the events table. The point of the foreign key is that you only need to store the user ID in the events table, because that is a REFERENCE to the user.

To get the user name for an event, say event number 6, you would do

```
select name from users join events on users.id = events.u_id where events.id = 6
```

So, you should not be trying to insert user data into the events table. Just put the ID in there, and the user data will be available for you to retrieve using the foreign key.